# AngularJS get request fail

Tags: angularjs, json, get, jsonp

I wrote some simple Angular code to make a GET request to several API's but it's not always working. For instance when i make a request to

> https://api.ofx.com/PublicSite.ApiService/OFX/spotrate/Individual/EUR/USD/10000?format=json

my code works perfectly.

But when using the same code and making a request to

> https://www.fcexchange.com/umbraco/api/CurrencyExchangeRateApi/GetRate?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&from=EUR&to=GBP

the code is not working. Upon inspecting the response i see the following error message:

> "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1".

Now after doing some searching i came across the use of JSONP. So i then changed my code to use $http.jsonp…
while also adding the "&callback=JSON_CALLBACK". I then checked my response (in the browser with firebug) and it received the JSON data successfully. However my Angularcode still throws me an error and it doesn't retrieve the response data for me.

(Also when I visit the URL in my browser I always get the JSON data).

I'm quite new to angularJS and just happened to stumble upon the JSONP method yesterday.
From what i have read i guess the server is not returning the expected format (it returns normal JSON without the callbackname) and therefor my code is throwing an error? Maybe the server is not using/allowing JSONP at all? But why do i seem to get the correct response then and not when using a normal GET request?

My code:

```
var frankComparesApp = angular.module('frankComparesApp', []);


frankComparesApp.controller('frankComparesCtrl', function($scope, $http) {  

$http.get('currency.json').then(function successCallback(response) {

  $scope.currencyOptions = response.data;
  $scope.choice = null;
}, function errorCall (response) {
  // Function for handling failure.

  $scope.currencyOptions=[];
}); // End of http.get

$scope.startComparing = function() {

$scope.ofxURL = 'https://www.fcexchange.com/umbraco/api/CurrencyExchangeRateApi/GetRate?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&from=EUR&to=GBP';
$http.jsonp($scope.ofxURL).then(function successCallback(response) {
  $scope.answer = response.data;
}, function errorCall (response) {
  $scope.answer = "fail";
}); // End of http.get
}; // End of startComparing();


}); // End of frankComparesCtrl
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like CORS issue. you're trying to request data from a domain different than `www.fcexchange.com` therefore you get an error like I did in this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/uzQ1MaGqQGgXXgUz1zsE?p=preview)

Check your console in devtools.

Comment: Did you even read my answer? plunkr is working alright. It's the request that's failing because of CORS issue. http://imgur.com/FP8dRpk

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However I was already aware of this as stated in my inital post. That is why i used JSONP instead of get (like in my examplecode). If you edit your plunkr example and use jsonp (+ add callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK' in your params) then you will see that now it does return the requested response in JSON when looked upon in the devtoolskit. It then probably errors the code because its not wrapped in javascript jsonp but is there a way to retrieve just the JSON because i'm getting the response back. Just need some way to push it to my code :)

Comment: You're right. check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26745389/2652883.
This is a valid JSONP response: https://angularjs.org/greet.php?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&name=Super%20Hero